# When to use a semi-colon between environment variables and a command

Tags: bash, shell-script

Can anyone explain why the semi-colon is necessary in order for the `LANG` to be seen as updated by bash?

Doesn't work:

```
> LANG=Ja_JP bash -c "echo $LANG"
en_US
```

Works:

```
> LANG=Ja_JP ; bash -c "echo $LANG"
Ja_JP
```

I'm working with both bash 4.1.10 on linux and the same version under cygwin

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Parameter and other types of expansions are performed when the command is read, *before* it is executed.

The first version, `LANG=Ja_JP bash -c "echo $LANG"`, is a single command. After it is parsed as such, `$LANG` is expanded to `en_US` before anything is executed.  Once `bash` is finished processing the input, it forks a process, adds `LANG=Ja_JP` to the environment as expected, and then executes `bash -c echo en_US`.

You can prevent expansion with single quotes, i.e. `LANG=Ja_JP bash -c 'echo $LANG'` outputs `Ja_JP`.

Note that when you have a variable assignment as part of a command, the assignment only affects the environment of that command and not that of your shell.

The second version, `LANG=Ja_JP; bash -c "echo $LANG"` is actually two separate commands executed in sequence.  The first is a simple variable assignment without a command, so it affects your current shell.

Thus, your two snippets are fundamentally different despite the superficial distinction of a single `;`.

<sup>Completely off-topic, but might I recommend appending a `.UTF-8` when setting `LANG`.  There's no good reason nowadays not to be using Unicode in the 21st century.</sup>

Comment: Great answer - thanks!  Regarding the addition of UTF-8.  I'm trying to test the locale handling of an application which needs to work on several platforms some of which are quite old.  Between differences like this one (which thankfully you've explained) and differences on linux and cygwin I'm about to throw myself under a bus!

Answer (score 7):

`VAR=value; somecommand` is equivalent to

```
VAR=value
somecommand
```

These are unrelated commands executed one after the other. The first command assigns a value to the shell variable `VAR`. Unless `VAR` is already an environment variable, it is not exported to the environment, it remains internal to the shell. A statement `export VAR` would export `VAR` to the environment.

`VAR=value somecommand` is a different syntax. The assignment `VAR=value` is to the environment, but this assignment is only made in the execution environment of `somecommand`, not for the subsequent execution of the shell.

By way of example:

```
# Assume neither VAR1 nor VAR2 is in the environment
VAR1=value
echo $VAR1                        # displays "value"
env | grep '^VAR1='               # displays nothing
VAR2=value env | grep '^VAR2='    # displays "VAR2=value"
echo $VAR2                        # displays nothing
```

Comment: I hadn't really thought about the difference between a shell vs environment variable.  I'll have to go do some research.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: why doesn't  'VAR1=123 echo $VAR1` work?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer It works (there's no error or anything), it just doesn't do what you expect. It prints the value of `VAR1` before the assignment, not the value after the assignment. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56444/how-do-i-set-an-environment-variable-on-the-command-line-and-have-it-appear-in-c

Comment: is there docs on `VAR=value somecommand` why shell var is getting treated like env var for somecommand?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Sure. For example [the POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01): “Variable assignments shall be performed as follows: (…)”. Or your shell's manual.

Answer (score 0):

This is the summary of what I gathered from research:

There are two types: env variables and shell variables.

An environment variable is available, in a program and its child programs/processes/subshells. A shell variable is only available in the current shell.

https://askubuntu.com/a/26322/326584

First how `echo $VAR` works

Whenever terminal/shell/bash sees $ symbol, it does something called "parameter expansion". Which means variables are replaced with values.

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

So if `VAR` had value 'hello' then `echo $VAR` becomes `echo 'hello'`.

which means this works...

```
TEST=123 
echo $TEST
// 123
```

but the following doesn't work because variable got replaced BEFORE the command was able to set the variable.

```
TEST2=999 echo $TEST2
// nothing...
```

but if you add the semicolon..

```
TEST2=999; echo $TEST2
```

it is same as..

```
TEST2=999
echo $TEST2
```

.. which works same as before.

And since shell variables are not passed to subprocesses/child, when you call a command it creates a new process, so...

```
TEST3=111 
node -e 'console.log(process.env.TEST3)'
```

or

```
TEST3=111 
printenv TEST3
```

both print nothing. Shell variables are not inherited by chld processes. Use export to make shell variable, an enviornment variable..

```
export TEST3=111 
printenv TEST3
//111
```

There is one exception...

```
VAR=123 printenv VAR
VAR=123 VAR2=456 printenv VAR2 //even multiple vars
```

Basically if written it like this and right after call the command then it only temporarily sets environment var for that command. It doesn't even set shell var. Think of it as completely new syntax.

```
VAR=123 printenv VAR // 123
echo $VAR // nothing
VAR=123
echo $VAR // 123
```