# How do I set an environment variable on the command line and have it appear in commands?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, echo

If I run

```
export TEST=foo
echo $TEST
```

It outputs foo.

If I run

```
TEST=foo echo $TEST
```

It does not. How can I get this functionality without using export or a script?

Comment: Careful, there is more to this story than initially appears. [I invite you to check my answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667284/how-do-i-keep-functions-variables-local-to-my-zshrc/42081254#42081254)

Comment: Related: [In bash, how do I define a "command scope" variable?](https://superuser.com/q/801822/354511)

Answer (score 427, accepted):

This is because the shell expands the variable in the command line **before** it actually runs the command and at that time the variable doesn't exist. If you use

```
TEST=foo; echo $TEST
```

it will work.

`export` will make the variable appear in the environment of subsequently executed commands (for on how this works in bash see `help export`). If you only need the variable to appear in the environment of one command, use what you have tried, i.e.:

```
TEST=foo your-application
```

The shell syntax describes this as being *functionally* equivalent to:

```
export TEST=foo
your-application
unset TEST
```

See [the specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) for details.

Interesting part is, that the `export` command switches the export flag for the variable **name**. Thus if you do:

```
unset TEST
export TEST
TEST="foo"
```

`TEST` will be exported even though it was not defined at the time when it was exported. However further `unset` should remove the export attribute from it.

Comment: What about /usr/bin/env? that doesn't work either, do you know why?

Comment: The same reason - the shell expands the `$TEST` before the command line is executed. Once the `echo` is running (also note that `echo` will usually  translate to the shell built-in command and not to `/bin/echo`) it sees  the variable set in  its environment. However, `echo $TEST` doesn't tell `echo` to output the contents of variable `TEST` from  its environment. It tells the shell to run `echo` with argument being whatever currently is in the variable called `TEST` - and those are two very different things.

Comment: @peterph If  shell expands the variable in the command line before it actually runs the command then why it doesn't expand it in `var=value sh -c 'echo "$var"'`?

Comment: As I explained to you [here](https://superuser.com/q/801822/354511#comment1934965_801830 "in a comment under my answer to «In bash, how do I define a “command scope” variable?»"): it’s because variables are expanded inside double quotes (e.g., ``"… $var …"``) but not inside single quotes (e.g., ``'… $var …'``).  Since `echo "$var"` is inside single quotes, that entire string gets passed to the new (`sh -c`) shell without being interpreted by the outer, interactive shell. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  As [igal said yesterday](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/429815/80216#comment776428_429828 "in a comment under their answer to your “Why cat command doesn’t use its command environment?” question"), there are two rounds of parsing — although I believe that igal misread your question.  There are not two rounds of parsing *apart from* the parsing that is done by the parent shell.  There are two rounds of parsing — one done by the outer, interactive (parent) shell,  and one by the new (`sh -c`) child shell.

Comment: @G-Man; I was almost convinced by his answer but then [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/429815/why-cat-command-doesnt-use-its-command-environment/429828?noredirect=1#comment776430_429828) came to my mind. But what I guess is that the second round of parsing is not done by a subshell, unlike it is done by a child process which is not a subhsell (like `sh -c`) .

Comment: If it's a one time variable that you don't what to be left behind, then unset it after using it. Ex. `TEST=foo; echo $TEST; unser TEST`

Comment: why TEST in `TEST=foo your-application` becomes env variable for your-application?

Comment: @MuhammadUmer because it is defined that way - check the link I've added to the answer.

Comment: If TEST is not defined, will export TEST define the variable TEST as empty value?

Comment: @Idonknow no, but `export TEST=` will; also see updated answer. And by the way, why not trying it yourself?

Comment: @peterph Do you know the windows alternative for the same?

Comment: @rbansal sorry, wrong site. :) You may want to ask that on [SU](https://superuser.com). I guess you will also need to elaborate on whether you are talking `cmd.exe` (the `command.com` descendant) or the PowersHell. (pun intended)

Comment: using two commands would work, but the reason why one simple command does not output `foo` IMO explained incorrectly, another answer is much better: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56454/266260: echo is usually a built-in and is not executed, `var=value sh -c 'echo "$var"'` works as one would expect.

Comment: What do you use to separate multiple env vars?

Answer (score 87):

I suspect you want to have **shell** variables to have a limited scope, rather than environment variables. Environment variables are a list of strings passed to commands when they are **executed**.

In

```
var=value echo whatever
```

You're passing the `var=value` string to the environment that echo receives. However, `echo` doesn't do anything with its environment list¹ and anyway in most shells, `echo` is built in and therefore not *executed*.

If you had written

```
var=value sh -c 'echo "$var"'
```

That would have been another matter. Here, we're passing `var=value` to the `sh` command, and `sh` does happen to use its environment. Shells convert each of the variables they receive from their environment to a shell variable, so the `var` environment variable `sh` receives will be converted to a `$var` variable, and when it expands it in that `echo` command line, that will become `echo value`. Because the environment is by default inherited, `echo` will also receive `var=value` in its environment (or would if it were executed), but again, `echo` doesn't care about the environment.

Now, if as I suspect, what you want is to limit the scope of shell variables, there are several possible approaches.

Portably (Bourne and POSIX):

```
(var=value; echo "1: $var"); echo "2: $var"
```

The (...) above starts a sub-shell (a new shell process in most shells), so any variable declared there will only affect that sub-shell, so I'd expect the code above to output "1: value" and "2: " or "2: whatever-var-was-set-to-before".

With most Bourne-like shells (see [List of shells that support `local` keyword for defining local variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/493729)), you can use functions and the "local" builtin:

```
f() {
  local var
  var=value
  echo "1: $var"
}
f
echo "2: $var"
```

With zsh, you can use [anonymous functions](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html#Anonymous-Functions) which like normal functions can have a local scope:

```
(){ local var=value; echo "1: $var"; }; echo "2: $var"
```

or:

```
function { local var=value; echo "1: $var"; }; echo "2: $var"
```

With bash and zsh (but not ash, pdksh or AT&T ksh), this trick also works:

```
var=value eval 'echo "1: $var"'; echo "2: $var"
```

A variant that works in a few more shells (`dash`, `mksh`, `yash`) but not `zsh` (unless in `sh`/`ksh` emulation):

```
var=value command eval 'echo "1: $var"'; echo "2: $var"
```

(using `command` in front of a special builtin (here `eval`) in POSIX shells removes their specialness (here that variables assignments in front of them remain in effect after they have returned))

With the `fish` shell, you can make variables local to a `begin`..`end` block:

```
begin
  set -l var value
  echo 1: $var
end
echo 2: $var
```

With `mksh` (and soon zsh), you can abuse the `${|cmd}` construct which can also have a local scope making sure it expands to nothing by making sure you don't set `$REPLY` within:

```
${|local var=value; echo "$var"}; echo "$var"
```

---

<sup>¹ Stricktly speaking, that's not completely true. Several implementations will care about the localisation environment variables (`LANG`, `LOCPATH`, `LC_*`...), the GNU implementation cares about the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable (compare `env echo --version` with `env POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 echo --version` on a GNU system).</sup>

Comment: For my purposes, this is the correct solution. I don't want the variable 'var' to pollute the environment as it does in the accepted answer.

Comment: If the simple subshell approach is "Portable (Bourne and POSIX)", why bother with all the more verbose answers for specific shells?

Comment: @Noumenon, because that approach has a side effect (runs in a subshell) that makes it unapplicable in man cases.

Answer (score 25):

You're doing it correctly, but the bash syntax is easy to misinterpret: you could think that `echo $TEST` causes `echo` to fetch `TEST` env var then print it, it does not. So given

```
export TEST=123
```

then

```
TEST=456 echo $TEST
```

involves the following sequence:

1. The shell parses the whole command line and executes all variable substitutions, so the command line becomes

   ```
   TEST=456 echo 123
   ```
2. It creates the temp vars set before the command, so it saves the current value of `TEST` and overwrites it with 456; the command line is now

   ```
   echo 123
   ```
3. It executes the remaining command, which in this case prints 123 to stdout (so shell command that remains didn't even use the temp value of `TEST`)
4. It restores the value of `TEST`

Use printenv instead, as it does not involve variable substitution:

```
>> export TEST=123
>> printenv TEST
123
>> TEST=456 printenv TEST
456
>> printenv TEST && TEST=456 printenv TEST && TEST=789 printenv TEST && printenv TEST
123
456
789
123
>>
```

Comment: +1 I found `printenv` helpful for testing / proof of concept (behaves like a script does, as opposed to `echo`)

Answer (score 10):

You can get this working by using:

```
TEST=foo && echo $TEST
```

Comment: In this case, `TEST=foo` is running as a separate statement - it is not just set in the context of `echo`.

Answer (score 2):

As you've already discovered, in Bash, `TEST=456 echo $TEST` doesn't work like you expected, because you are accessing the variable on the same line that's currently being interpreted by the shell. But rest assured, the variable has been set for the duration of the current command. To verify that, you could do something like this:

```bsh
show () { echo "${!1}" ;}
TEST=456 show TEST
```