# How to execute more than one command in a newly opened terminal?

Tags: shell-script, terminal

I have a script that I want to use to open new terminals and type commands in them. A command like

```
gnome-terminal
```

opens a new terminal.

Also, if I do

```
gnome-terminal -e myprogram1
```

it will execute myprogram1 in the newly opened terminal. But what if, after myprogram1 completes, I want to execute myprogram2? I cannot do something like

```
gnome-terminal -e myprogram2
```

because it will open a new terminal.

Is there a way to specify in the script that I want to execute both `myprogram1` and `myprogram 2` in the same new terminal? Or would I have to create a new script and do something like

```
gnome-terminal -e scriptToExecuteMyPrograms1And2
```

Comment: Similar: [hold, -H in xfce4-terminal (and probably other graphical wrappers for terminals)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75902/22565)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want like this:

```
$ gnome-terminal -e "bash -c '<cmd1>;<cmd2>;exec $SHELL'"
```

This will open up `<cmd1>`, when that's complete, it will open up `<cmd2>`, finally it will leave you at a command prompt `exec $SHELL`.

For example:

```
$ gnome-terminal -e "bash -c 'vim;vim;exec $SHELL'"
```

Runs `vim`, if I close the 1st `vim`, a 2nd `vim` is started. When the 2nd one closes I'm left at a terminal prompt.

Comment: I tried to do exec $SHELL in the beginning,to show the command prompt, but that stopped the rest of the commands from executing. Why so?

Comment: Because that's what `exec` does.

Comment: I want to see the prompt each time before a command begins execution.

Comment: @CodeBlue - `exec $SHELL` replaces the shell without creating a new process. Seeing the command prompt before each command  begins isn't feasible here given there isn't a prompt to show. Bash is run via the `-e`, it would normally display a prompt, but in this case we're telling Bash to run commands, `-c`, so `cmd#1` runs, when it's done, `cmd#2` is run by Bash. When `cmd#2` runs, we tell Bash to replace itself (`exec ...`) with `$SHELL`, which is `/bin/bash`. The `exec $SHELL` is the first time where there is actually a prompt to display.

Answer (score 1):

Try `gnome-terminal -e "myprogram1; myprogram2"`. You could also try with a `&&` instead of `;`.

Comment: Keep in mind that `myprogram1; myprogram2` is different than `myprogram1 && myprogram2`. The semicolon `;` means that `myprogram2` is executed after `myprogram1`, regardless of its return state (whether execution was successful, or returned an error). `&&` means that `myprogram2` is executed **only** if `myprogram1` ran successfully. You can see an example of this when you compile programs from source: `./configure && make && make install` means the execution of each successive program is dependent on the successful execution of the previous command - `make install` won't run if `make` failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute many commands after firing up the terminal then a better approach would be to write a function, export that and call that function. Create a shell script similar to one given below to suit your application:

```
my_function(){
    command1
    command2
    .
    .
    .
    commandn
}

export -f my_function

$(x-terminal-emulator -e "bash -c 'my_function'")
```

You can also have more than one function. But, then you will have to write another function which acts like main i.e. which calls all the other functions. So, you set your terminal to execute this main function which will take care of the rest.

Answer (score -2):

You can put the programs in `~/.bashrc` file

This is valid for **bash** shell if you are using it.
Whenever you open the terminal, eitheir through tty or gnome-terminal it will execute.

Basically, you just add at the end of the file your programs to be executed.

Comment: this could be dangerous, or not quite what the OP wants, as those commands would be executed **every time** you open a bash login shell. Maybe that is what he wants, but I try to keep my `.bashrc` free of stuff that runs automatically (unless I **really** want it to run every time, like setting up env. variables) and instead put conditionals in, such as checking to make sure I'm in X, etc.