# Commands run when terminal is open do not appear in history

Tags: bash, command-history

I have the simple following `terminal.sh` script:

```
#bin/bash --login
str=(--tab --title="Test" -e "bash --login -c 'echo history';bash")
gnome-terminal "${str[@]}"
exit 0
```

I basically use it to open a terminal with several tabs that I need to use daily. But the problem is that the `echo history` command is not added to the history of that tab. So, for example, one of my tabs is the application server. When I need to restart it, I usually type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but when I use this script to run it, it doesn't add the line executed to the bash, and then the last command executed is normally `exit`. So I end up closing the tab instead of restarting the server, which is incredbly annoying.

I saw [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5684/history-command-inside-bash-script), and I tried adding:

```
HISTFILE=~/.bash_history
set -o history
```

To the start of my `terminal.sh` script, and also tried adding to the script executed:

```
str=(--tab --title="Test" -e "bash --login -c 'HISTFILE=~/.bash_history;set -o history;echo a';bash")
```

But neither helped. I also tried adding `history -s echo history` before executing the script, but that didn't help either.

How can I add all commands executed this way to the history?

I aslo tried:

```
#bin/bash --login

cmd='echo test'
cmd_e="bash --login -c 'unset PROMPT_COMMAND;history -s '\''$cmd'\''; eval '\''$cmd'\''';bash"
str=(--tab --title="History Test" -e "$cmd_e")

gnome-terminal "${str[@]}"

exit 0
```

Comment: See [this answer to a related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/77556/22565) (that's for xfce-terminal but can be adapted to your usage).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash PROMPT_COMMAND='unset PROMPT_COMMAND; history -s "$CMD";
    eval "$CMD"' CMD='vi /etc/issue' gnome-terminal
```

(here using `vi /etc/issue` as your command).

That has the advantage of running `$CMD` as a job of that shell, so you can suspend resume, interrupt it as other jobs and it can affect the environment of the shell (for instance you can do `CMD='PATH=$foo:$PATH'`).

It assumes your `~/.bashrc` doesn't set `$PROMPT_COMMAND` itself.

#### Edit:

For multiple tabs:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='unset PROMPT_COMMAND; history -s "$CMD"; eval "$CMD"
  ' gnome-terminal --tab --title /etc/issue -e 'env CMD="vi /etc/issue" bash' \
                   --tab --title who -e 'env CMD=who bash'
```

Comment: Your code work flawlessly the way it is! But I'm having trouble integrating it with mine... I need my syntax because I need to open multiple tabs in the same terminal, each one with one title. I added how I did it on the question. It runs, echoes, but doesn't add...