# Reattach a program to stdin

Tags: linux, shell, tty

Suppose you want to have a program that ingest a string and then reattach `stdin` when done.

I know that it is possible to do so by doing this trick:

`(echo id; cat) | sh`

Which works well. It doesn't close `stdin` since it is used by `cat`. But the output is messy.

Digging deeper I understood that it is lacking of a `tty`.

If my comprehension is right, `sh` being in a pipe didn't open a `tty`.

The trick I've found is to use `expect`.

Simply put this in a file:

```
spawn sh
reattach
```

Then when `cat` gives you back the control, do:

```
expect exp.sh
```

This is nice because it gives me a `tty` to do everything I need: `ssh`, `tmux` and so on...

The only thing I don't understand why is that I see everything I typed, back to my terminal.

Example:

```
(echo whoami; cat) | sh
moon
expect exp.sh
spawn sh
sh-3.2$ whoami
whoami
moon
```

Note the `whoami` output back before my login on the last line.

Could somebody explain to me why? It is obviously not a property of `stdout` from `cat` because it is attached to `sh` directly -- yes, even if it was dumb I tried the following: `(echo id; cat > /dev/null) | sh` then nothing happened.

So is it a property of a `tty`/`pty` to not display back what has been typed from the keyboard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{ echo 'exec <&3 3<&-; id' | sh -si; } 3<&0
```

Seems to work with most `sh` implementations. We ask for an interactive shell with `-i` (otherwise, some shells would disable it on the ground that stdin is not a terminal device), start with the shell's stdin being the pipe, but then with `exec <&3` instruct it to change it to the original (outer) stdin which we've saved earlier on the file descriptor 3 with `3<&0`.

We do that *before* running `id` but still on the same command *line*, so that stdin is restored for `id` as well. It doesn't matter for `id` as it doesn't read its stdin, but it would be interactive commands like editors or shells.

As to why you see what you type in `(echo id | cat) | sh`. It looks like your implementation of `sh` which seems to be a very old version of `bash` is running in interactive mode. You can see that with the fact that it is issuing a prompt as if `-i` was used.

Then it does implement its own line editor, but fails to disable the tty device own line editor (because its stdin is the pipe and not the tty  device), so you get the echo of what you type by the tty device line discipline, and once you press enter, `cat` sees all the content of that line buffer including a trailing newline at once from the pipe which it writes straight away to `bash`, and `bash` outputs the `echo` of that as part of its own line editor.

I suspect that if you did:

```
stty -icanon -echo; (echo id; cat) | sh; stty sane
```

You'd get a better behaviour, and may be able to use readline line editing functionalities as `bash` would receive every character you type directly as they come.

For other options to have a command been run automatically before the user takes over an interactive shell, see:

- [How to run xfce-terminal with different commands per tab and keep using the tabs after the commands have returned?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75902)
- [Commands run when terminal is open do not appear in history](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131306)
- [How to automatically insert a string after the prompt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/391679)

Comment: Thank you Steph! it was really informative and I'm learning a lot.
Your first example works perfectly, the last one works too but as you might have suspected, I need to do the `expect` trick, once it is done, it works very well.


I am slowly going to digest everything and really understand what your wrote. I might be back with some questions too!