# Can I set an enviroment variable for a single anacron command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, anacron

Consider the following anacrontab file:

```
1 0 bob-job /home/bob/script.sh
```

I know I can set variables like this:

```
FOO=bar
1 0 bob-job /home/bob/script.sh
```

However, can I set a variable just for the `bob-job` line?

I know I can do:

```
FOO=bar
1 0 bob-job /home/bob/script.sh
FOO=
```

... but this is not equivalent because it clobbers the existing value of FOO, if any (from the parent environment of anacron), and setting `FOO=` to empty is not also equivalent to unset.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this script? Is `FOO` being used anywhere else in the script? If not, then why do you need to unset it? If you need to do it for some other reason, then use `unset FOO`.

Comment: Consider https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56444/117549

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `env` utility:

```
1 0 bob-job    env FOO=bar /home/bob/script.sh
```

The `env` utility sets one or several environment variables (or clears the environment with `-i`) and executes the given utility (your script) with the modified environment.

See `man env` on your system.